# Unable to find cloudwatch logs for certain interactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have Lambdas running that are behind an API Gateway. They log to Cloudwatch for every interaction.

Behaviour experienced:

There are logs missing, for certain time stamps. I know the interactions occurred due to having tracked them externally as well outside of Cloudwatch. The logs itself are fine for the day and during the duration in question.

Any ideas as to how this could happen?

Comment: For certain requests, the request stops at the API level, especially for non-proxy integrations when e.g. validation fails on the API level. In that case, you will not see lambda logs, but you should still see e.g. API Gateway access logs if you enabled them. Might this be the case for you?